# VScode shortcut for comment

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

Using Vscode in Laravel ..

when selecting a part of line and press `ctrl + /` it comment the whole line with `{{--   --}}`

1- I don't want to comment the whole line , just the selected part

2- I want to use `<!--  -->` instead of `{{--  --}}`

Comment: In blade it will use the `{{--  --}}`, because `<!--  -->` comment won't comment out the blade snippets

Comment: is there any shortcut to use <!-- --> ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For

> 1- I don't want to comment the whole line , just the selected part.

This keyboard shortcut will work for you.

> Shift+Alt+A

Answer (score 2):

Add a Comment
ctrl + /

Moving a lineup or down
alt + up arrow/down arrow

Cut an entire line
ctrl + x

Copy an entire line
ctrl + c

Quickly open a file
ctrl + p

Move to the desired line number
ctrl + g

Move to any file within the project
ctrl + e

Hide/Show Sidebar
ctrl + b

Select the current line and move the cursor to the next line
ctrl + l

Show/Hide the terminal
ctrl + j

Select and Edit multiple lines
alt + cursor
drag middle mouse key

Search any word
ctrl + f

Search & Replace any word
ctrl + h

See previous selections/cursor movements
ctrl + u

Quickly close a file
ctrl + w

Switch between sidebar services
ctrl + q

Open the current folder in the browser
alt + l + o

Answer (score 0):

Select your interested code

`Ctrl k + C` -----> for comment

`Ctrl k + U` -----> for Un-comment

These shortcuts work for all supported languages in VScode